# Custom UIVIew is not shown

Tags: swift, uiview

I have created a simple UIView class that will show a label on runtime.

```
@IBDesignable
class CalendarDayView: UIView {

    var dayLabel = UILabel()

    @IBInspectable
    var day: Int {
        set {
            dayLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
        get {
            return Int(dayLabel.text!)!
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        prepareSubviews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        prepareSubviews()
    }

    func prepareSubviews() {
        dayLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        addSubview(dayLabel)
        dayLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor)
        dayLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
        dayLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor)
        dayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

I have added a UIView on a simple view controller in the story board and set its width and height as 100. In the attribute inspector, the day value is set as 1.

I don't get to see the custom view background color (which should be blue) nor the label (which should show 1). Did I miss out something?

Comment: Did you set the width and height of `dayLabel`?

Comment: Shouldn't the auto layout constraints take care of that?

Comment: However, you may need to set `dayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Also, are you explicitly setting the frame of the `CalendarDayView`? Try putting in a breakpoint and printing out the frame after it has been initialized and added to whatever superview you added it to.

Comment: That does not resolve why my custom view background color is not shown.

Comment: And you probably want to change your `day` to the following, if possible (not sure how Interface Builder handles this): `var day: Int = defaultDayValue { didSet { dayLabel.text = "\(day)" } }`

Comment: Do I have to set the size of the CalendarDayView when I have set it through storyboard with specific size and center to the superview?

Comment: @BallpointBen your suggestion of having a new variable will notsolve the inspectable attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I've probably had this error myself 1000 times, can't believe I didn't recognize it at first glance (then again that's probably why I've had it 1000 times).

```
// .isActive = true
dayLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
dayLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
dayLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
dayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: "dayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false" helped. what does this do?

Comment: iOS will automatically generate constraints for programmatically created UIViews. These will conflict with any constraints you add yourself. That line tells IOS not to create those constraints so that the only constraints that matter are the ones you create programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but what will IOS generate as default constraint?

Comment: Not exactly sure. I think it's based on how you set the frame bounds and position, and then how you set up the auto resizing mask. I've always found it too complicated to be worth it. Instead, I write a `UIView` extension that encapsulates all of the AutoLayout functionality. I really don't like Interface Builder, either.